# jQuery Arrays and a Dropdown Menu

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, drop-down-menu, nested

I've been looking around and I feel like i'm really jumping a learning curve here and my head is about to explode from searching so much and coming up with nothing.

My problem is that I have a horizontal menu, designed with unordered lists, and to make it a dropdown menu i nested unordered lists in the first unordered list.

```
<ul class="top-level">
   <li><a href="#"></a>
       <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"></a>
          </li>
       <ul>
   <li>
</ul>
```

Now, the nested unordered list is set to "Display:None;".

Since I have all the dropdown lists in the same class, when I try to toggle the 'Display:None;' attribute to 'Display: Block' ALL of the dropdown lists get toggled.

I know I can probably put each of the dropdown lists into their own seperate classes, but is there a way to do this with an array? To be able to click on a top-level list item and bring the appropriate dropdown list.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("ul.top-level li").click(function(event) {
    $(this).find("ul.dropdown").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
$(".top-level").on("click", "a", function() {
  $(this).next("ul.dropdown").toggle(); // Show / hide the corresponding sub-menu
});
```